# Putting a Red Hat Enterprise Linux installation image on a bootable USB mass storage

Tags: linux, redhat

I need to install Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 5 on a non-networked server, and I'm out of CD/DVDs. However, I do have a USB mass storage, but I can not figure out how to use it instead of a blank DVD.

I have found the following guide https://access.redhat.com/kb/docs/DOC-10553 - but it requires a computer already running Linux, and I only have one running Windows 7.

How can I put the install images on a USB mass storage so it works same as a DVD?

Comment: I'd recommend getting a copy of VirtualBox and installing a Linux guest, with which you can set up the USB stick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for your suggestions.
In the end I managed to use [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/), choosing "Try Unlisted Linux ISO (New Syslinux)" and choose the install ISO image to transfer to the USB pen. This USB pen would boot up the Red Hat installer fine, but the installer can not find the files for installation because it expects a CD/DVD with unpacked files, or a HDD with the ISO image (and the USB pen is recognized as a HDD).
The solution for me was to take out the USB pen, put it in my windows machine, format it with FAT32, copy the ISO image file directly to the USB pen, put it back in the machine running the linux install and let find the drive under "harddisk".

I believe it would also be possible to copy the ISO image to the USB pen togeather with the install files if the USB pen has enough space, or use 2 USB pens (one with install files, and one with ISO image).

Hope it will help someone else in the future :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with RHEL, however I believe [UNbetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) (has a windows version), it should work.

Also check http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-create-a-bootable-usb-pen/ and http://forums.techarena.in/operating-systems/1284255.htm

**Edit:**

also check this, while it's mostly for Arch Linux, it should work with RHEL as well https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/USB_Installation_Media#On_Windows .

Answer (score 0):

Short term, I'd really suggest buying a DVD if the server is non-networked. That's the path of least-resistance. The article you linked basically describes using a small bootable USB key to bootstrap a network-based RHEL installation.